# Two Android System apps after AVG/Avast flagged it as false positive. Normal?

Tags: samsung, malware, system-apps, virus

I have a Samsung s22. Yesterday AVG flagged an "Android system" app as malware with no ability to disable it. Appears it happened to many people. AVG looked into it and declared it to be a false positive on their end (https://support.avg.com/answers?id=9065p000000kHo1).

However, I'm still a bit confused about why there are two Android system apps showing? Is this normal? (One spelled "Android System" and one "Android system"). Android system one has no option to disable it and is only 168kb in size.

Thank you all

[image]

Comment: A name like "Android System" can belong to any app including third party and malware. So the name is pretty useless. Instead look at the package name and search in Google for it. The "Android System" app that belongs to Android has the package name `android`.

Comment: Thanks Robert. How can I find the package name?

Comment: Figured it out. The package name is com.google.android.adservices.api

Comment: @PaulM111 from the [official Android Developer site](https://source.android.com/docs/core/ota/modular-system/adservices), this is a new module introduced in Android 13.

Comment: not sure about S22 but system apps can replaced with malicious updates on same pkgname. you can try uninstall update from adb to ensure it's the stock version, then scan again https://www.xda-developers.com/android-oem-key-leak-samsung-lg-mediatek

Comment: Thanks, got rid of it using adb